# Interface for AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, appcompatactivity

I want to extend both AppCompatActivity, Fragment activity because I use this code

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

My Java file wants to extend AppCompatActivity but I'm using map in that Activity so it already extends FragmentActivity

Since Java does not not support multiple inheritance, are there any interfaces instead of AppCompatActivity or FragmentActivity I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AppCompatActivity` is a subclass of `FragmentActivity`. So you can use `AppCompatActivity` in place of `FragmentActivity`.

If you do not want to use `AppCompatActivity`, use `setActionBar(toolbar)` instead of `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

Comment: Thanks ! It motivates me to use the documentation more than the Stack over flow :)